# Extract specific Z file method

Tags: ftp, wget, extract

I downloaded files from `ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex` via

```
wget -r -nc ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex
```

distribution by years from 1998 to 2016 and per years contain 365 or 366 days

[image]

It contains these files (or similar) for each day

[image]

I  want to extract only the files beginning with "codg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple script which will extract files from the current directory.

```
cat > /tmp/extract.sh <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
for x in "$@"; do
  uncompress -f "${x}"
  rm -f "${x}"
done
EOF
chmod 755 /tmp/extract.sh
```

Then use a find command to iterate through the directories to do the operation of that script on every file.

```
find . -type f -name 'codg*.Z' -execdir /tmp/extract.sh {} +
```

The find command should be executed from the directory of your downloaded files.  See [`find(1)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) and understand the options before executing.

Comment: codg... already exists;  do you wish to overwrite (y or no)?
I have very large data.  I receive same warning when I use "y".

Comment: In addition, compressed files beginning with "codg" can be removable after this files extract ?

Comment: Perhaps better elaborate on your goal?  If you're getting prompts then see the man page for ways to suppress them.  You'll need to explain more the purpose of these files and how you'll use them before I can help further.

Comment: First of all, I am due to beginner  I made a hash of ! Hence, I downloaded from different way via <wget -r  -A 'codg*' ftp://cddis.nasa.gov/gnss/products/ionex> from 1998 to 2016. Thus, I just obtained only the files beginnig with ''codg''.
I wanna extract this files in this directory or sub-directory than remove existing this Z file extension after extract processing.
My aim is to get some values specific geopraphical coordinates in this ionex files.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to update my answer with that in mind.